# Sencha Nested List displays no items

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

Ahoy,

I am trying to develop a nested list demo by going through sencha docs and other example available over internet. Till now this is what I have achieved:

**Sencha App Model Folder**

*Filename: item.js*

```
Ext.define('firstApp.model.item', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        config: {
            fields: [{
                name: 'text',
                type: 'string'
            }]
        }
});
```

**Sencha App Store Folder**

*Filename: nList.js (items listed are from sencha docs)*

```
var treeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
model: 'item',
defaultRootProperty: 'items',
root: {
    items: [
        {
            text: 'Heavy Metal',
            items: [
                {
                    text: 'NWOBHM',
                    items: [
                        { text: 'Iron Maiden', leaf: true },
                         ]
                },
                { text: 'MetalCore', leaf: true }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'Extreme Metal',
            items: [
                { text: 'Children Of Bodom', leaf: true },
                { text: 'Cannibal Corpse', leaf: true },
                { text: 'Cradle Of Filth', leaf: true  }
            ]
        }
    ]
 }
});


Ext.create('firstApp.store.nList',{
  extend:'Ext.NestedList',
  requires: {'Ext.dataview.NestedList'},
  config:{
     fullscreen: false,
     store: treeStore
    }
 });
```

**Sencha App Views Folder**

*Filename : Main.js*

```
Ext.define('firstApp.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'main',
requires: [
   'Ext.TitleBar',
   'Ext.Button',
   //'firstApp.model.item',
  // 'firstApp.store.nList',
   //'Ext.dataview.NestedList',
   //'Ext.data.TreeStore'
   //'Ext.ToolBar'
] ,
config: {
//store: 'firstApp.store.Main',
    items: [

            {

            xtype: "toolbar",
            docked: "top",
            title: "List View",
            items: [
                    {
                        xtype: "spacer"
                    }, 
                    {
                        xtype: "button",
                        text: "Tab View",
                        ui: "action",
                        handler: function(){                    
                              Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem((
                                          Ext.create('firstApp.view.view2')),
                                          {type: 'slide', direction:'left'}).show();
                            }                           
                    }
                    ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'nestedlist',
                displayField: 'text',
                model: 'item',
                store: 'nList'
                }


            ]

            }




});
```

**Console.log**

*These are the warnings I am getting*

1.[WARN][Ext.dataview.NestedList#applyStore] The specified Store cannot be found .

2.[WARN][Anonymous] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'Ext.dataview.NestedList'; consider adding 'Ext.dataview.NestedList' explicitly as a require of the corresponding class .

**Here's the snapshot**

[image: Sencha View with no nested list]

**What could be going wrong ?**

1. I know that nested list comes with a titlebar but what if I want to add nested list as an item.
2. When I followed the [GitHub Demo of Nested List](https://github.com/senchalearn/Nested-list-demo) by copying and pasting the contents in the Main.js of my app and commenting out the rest of the code accordingly, the example worked. But a major difference in the example and my exmple is that Store, Model and View are in one js while in my case they are in separate js and in separate folder.

Kindly, guide me/help me out.

Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the `layout: 'fit'` property to your nestedList.

Main.js

```
Ext.define('firstApp.view.Main', {
    extend : 'Ext.Container',
    xtype : 'main',
    config : {
        fullscreen : true,
        layout : 'fit',
        items : [{
            xtype : "toolbar",
...
```

Then change your store to the following:

nList.js

```
Ext.define('firstApp.store.nList', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    config : {
        model : 'firstApp.model.Item',
        defaultRootProperty : 'items',
        data : {
            items : [{
                text : 'Heavy Metal',
                items : [{
                    text : 'NWOBHM',
                    items : [{
                        text : 'Iron Maiden',
                        leaf : true
                    }]
                }, {
                    text : 'MetalCore',
                    leaf : true
                }]
            }, {
                text : 'Extreme Metal',
                items : [{
                    text : 'Children Of Bodom',
                    leaf : true
                }, {
                    text : 'Cannibal Corpse',
                    leaf : true
                }, {
                    text : 'Cradle Of Filth',
                    leaf : true
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

The problem was, that you defined a nested List in your store and not just the store, which should be added to the list in your 'Main'-view. Then the data in the store needs the tag `data` not `root`

See a working example : http://www.senchafiddle.com/#ERFUC

**EDIT**

Add the following parts in your app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'firstApp',
    views:['Main'],
    stores:['nList'],
    models:['Item'],
```

You can find the whole app.js in the fiddle above.

Comment: I used the same code as yours in sencha fiddle and I am still getting the same warning

Comment: Did you add the store and model in app.js?

Comment: Did you uncomment this `//'Ext.dataview.NestedList',` from main.js ?

Comment: nope i didnt added store and model in app.js...how would i do that could u please help me out @LucasK

Comment: I edited my post with the settings for app.js. You can find it also in the fiddle

Comment: now only 3 dots are being displayed as loading...nothing else

Comment: @LukasK. the problem was restructuring and comma.